# Simple command completion using _alternative in zsh

Tags: zsh, completion

Finally getting around to switching to zsh (from bash)...  I'm trying to understand a bit more about the completion system and could use a quick pointer.  I have been able to get other completions to work for command arguments, but I'm struggling with path completions.

I use a simple function (`cdp`) to jump to project directories.  I've set up a very basic completion script, which almost works.  I just can't seem to get the behavior that I'm hoping for.

Ideally, typing `cdp in{tab}` would expand to all projects starting with `in`, such as:

```
~/Projects/indigo ~/Projects/instant
```

Instead, I can only get `cdp {tab}` to get the `~/Projects` path.  From there, it will expand the first-level directory.  I'd like to be able to just run standard completion for `cd` once the project directory is expanded.

Here is the completion script, save in `_cdp` and added to `fpath`:

```zsh
#compdef cdp

basedir="$HOME/Projects"

# the function for jumping to directories...
cdp() {
  if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    cd $basedir
  else
    cd "$1"
  fi
}

# completion helper...
_alternative "directories:user directory:($basedir/*)"
```

It's pretty basic, I'm just stuck trying to sort out where to go next.  Any thoughts or pointers would be great.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I'm finding that `cdpath` works fine for most of what I need...  It would still be interesting to know how to complete this simple function, but for now at least I have a working solution using `cdpath` and `auto_cd`.